# Button Click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to jQuery. I want to use a button click event to raise an alert box. This is my code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Jquery Basic</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('submit1').click(function() {
                    alert("JQuery Running!");
                )};
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>JQuery Test Page</a><br>
        <input id="submit1" type="button" value="Submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is your fixed javascript http://jsfiddle.net/3e2Rr/. You had to select the button with # like in CSS

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are missing the `#` from your `id` selector. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit1').click(function(){
        alert("JQuery Running!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! So hey what do I do if I want to copy the value entered into a textbox into a paragraph on button click. Code is as follows. Click works. Copying part does'nt.

Comment: @Sirakhil you may want to start a new question for that, but something like `$x.click(function() { $p.append($input.val()); });`

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit1").click(function() {
        alert("click");
        $("#para1").val = $("#textbox").val;
    });
});

</script>   <div>
<div id="heading1"><a>Name:</a></div>
<div><input id="textbox" type="text"/></div>
<button id="submit1">Submit</button>
</div>

<div><p id="para1"></p></div>

Comment: `p` tags don't have a value - you need to set the `text`: `$("#para1").text($("#textbox").val());`. Or see my previous comment to `append`

Comment: No need! "$("#para1").text($("#textbox").val());" Worked like a charm. Thanks again!!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan line 4 there is a small error  `)};`  should be `});`

Comment: @guillaumevincent good eye - you're the first person in 18 months to spot it :)

Answer (score 3):

Answer already posted by @Rory, but you can also try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit1').on('click',function(){
        alert("JQuery Running!");
    });
});
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but probably because you told someone else to remove their duplicate answer, then posted the exact same answer yourself. A little under handed really.

Comment: But handler is different, So I post this answer and mention in first line. This is also a way.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `#` before your `id`. You need to use `#` if you want to select based on `id` and `.` if you want to select based on `css-class`.

Try `$('#submit1').click(function(){`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the value of input i "textbox" and put the value in paragraph "para1" it solves, if your doubt is. I have helped. :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit1").click(function() {
        alert($("#textbox").val());
        $("#para1").text($("#textbox").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit1").live('click',function() {
       alert("hi!");
    });
});
```