# Click event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry for a duplicated question but I'm not solving this utterly easy(hard?) code problem.
Yes I have tried [Rory McCrossan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243559/button-click-in-jquery) solution but it still doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script> $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sta').on('click', function(){
            alert("Hi");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="name"></p>
<input type="button" id="sta" value="Click me"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you have in console?

Comment: You have not included the jquery.

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery

Comment: @Tibbers I am guessing "TypeError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @TimSeguine yep, simply jQuery hasn't been included.

Comment: Oh, what a silly mistake. I though it was enough if you downloaded the jquery library in WebStorm. Hence not including JQuery. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mnemonics your mistake wasn't not including jQuery. Anyone can do that accidentally from time to time. I have done it myself. Your mistake was not looking in the web console to see if you were getting javascript errors.

Comment: @Mnemonics it happens to all of us! don't worry. But the main thing if your coding on js/jquery - console should be your best friend. It will show everything what is missing or should be improved.

Comment: @TimSeguine yeah the thing is that it's my first try on web devlopment(and the IDE) and when  Tibbers asked about the errors on the console I directly started finding information how to make the console visible. As you said, it was a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"-error. Thanks

Comment: @Mnemonics yeah it is fine, I just wanted to make sure you "got the point" and know how to find the problem if something else happens in the future. Just telling you that you need jQuery is a lot less helpful than telling you how you might have been able to answer your own question. It is something everyone has to learn at some point. You learned it today.

Comment: You wont see me asking this type of questions, which is not preferable here, thats for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you've not linked the jQuery library to your HTML document. That is why you cannot execute a jQuery code in your page.

Try the pure JavaScript code to alert,

```
<input type="button" onclick="showAlert()" id="sta" value="Click me"/>
```

JavaScript function as,

```
function showAlert() {
  alert('Hello world!');
}
```

or you can try adding the jQuery library here.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

These methods would remove this error.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code - http://jsfiddle.net/ye5Ltuj7/

Seems like you forgot to add a `jQuery.js`

Just simply add it to the header.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using jQuery in your javascript, but jQuery is not included on the page. Try adding this line:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

in your header above your `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include query library. Include below line in your code which is the latest jquery library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How ever don't depend on jquery for simple tasks like these. Page loading time will be increased as it has to load jquery library from internet. You can use the code below which will do same thing as the jquery code.

```
<input type="button" id="sta" value="Click me" on click="alert("Hi")"/>
```